# Is it possible to selecting dataset by time range when range is different for every pixel in pythons xarray module

Tags: python, indexing, multi-index, python-xarray

I try to select only this part of the data within a specific time range that is different for every pixel.

For indexing, I have two np.datetime64[ns] xr.DataArrays with shape(lat:152, lon:131) named time_range_min, time_range_max
One is holding the start dates and the other one the end dates.

I try this for selecting the data

```
dataset = data.sel(time=slice(time_range_min, time_range_max))
```

but it yields

> cannot use non-scalar arrays in a slice for xarray indexing:
> <xarray.DataArray 'NDVI' (lat: 152, lon: 131)>

If I cannot use non-scalar arrays it means that it is in general not possible to do this, or can I transform my arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "time" is a list of dates in `str`ing that is ordered from past to present (e.g. ["10-20-2021", "10-21-2021", ...]:

```
import numpy as np
listOfMinMaxTimeRanges = [time_range_min, time_range_max]
specifiedRangeOfTimeIndexedList = []
for indexingListOfMinMaxTimeRanges in range(len(listOfMinMaxTimeRanges)):
    specifiedRangeOfTimeIndexed = [specifiedRangeOfTime for specifiedRangeOfTime in np.arange(0, len(time), 1) if time.index(listOfMinMaxTimeRanges[0][indexingListOfMinMaxTimeRanges]) <= specifiedRangeOfTime <= time.index(listOfMinMaxTimeRanges[1][indexingListOfMinMaxTimeRanges])]
    for indexes in specifiedRangeOfTimeIndexed:
        specifiedRangeOfTimeIndexedList.append(indexes)
```

Depending on how your dataset is structured:

```
dataset = data.sel(time = specifiedRangeOfTimeIndexedList)
```

or

```
dataset = data.sel(time = time[specifiedRangeOfTimeIndexedList])
```

or

```
dataset = dataset[time[specifiedRangeOfTimeIndexedList]]
```

or

```
dataset = dataset[:, time[specifiedRangeOfTimeIndexedList]]
```

or

```
dataset = dataset[time[specifiedRangeOfTimeIndexedList], :, :]
```

or

```
dataset = dataset[specifiedRangeOfTimeIndexedList]
```

...

Comment: `range(listOfMinMaxTimeRanges.shape[1])` results in an error, because that a list doesn't have a `shape`. Could you please revise this answer? It's very difficult to determine what it's meant to be doing.

I presume the `time` list would be better represented as an array of datetime objects, obtained from the `dataset` that is actually being selected. Including that would be helpful.

Comment: @alphabetasoup I just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to group every cell with [stacking](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/groupby.html?highlight=stacking#multidimensional-grouping) in xarray:
time_range_min and time_range_max marks now a single date

```
stack = dataset.value.stack(gridcell=['lat', 'lon'])
for unique_value, grouped_array in stack.groupby('gridcell'):
    grouped_array.sel(time=slice(time_range_min,time_range_max))
```