# How to select lat/lon data with time slices that are functions of location

Tags: time, geospatial, python-xarray

I have a daily record of rainfall for several years, an `xarray.Dataset`

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (longitude: 243, latitude: 260, time: 1826)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 166.4 166.5 166.5 166.6 ... 178.4 178.5 178.5
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -34.38 -34.42 -34.47 ... -47.22 -47.28 -47.33
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2006-01-01 2006-01-02 ... 2010-12-31
Data variables:
    rain       (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1826, 1, 1), meta=np.ndarray>
```

I also have two `xarray.DataArray` objects that have the following structure (noting that I have truncated this for display; the longitude and latitude dimensions are actually the same across all data):

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 4, longitude: 2, latitude: 2)>
array([[[datetime.date(2007, 3, 23), datetime.date(2007, 4, 26)],
        [datetime.date(2007, 5, 18), datetime.date(2007, 4, 20)]],

       [[datetime.date(2008, 3, 25), datetime.date(2008, 5, 6)],
        [datetime.date(2008, 5, 30), datetime.date(2008, 4, 25)]],

       [[datetime.date(2009, 3, 28), datetime.date(2009, 5, 4)],
        [datetime.date(2009, 5, 29), datetime.date(2009, 4, 23)]],

       [[datetime.date(2010, 3, 18), datetime.date(2010, 4, 16)],
        [datetime.date(2010, 5, 5), datetime.date(2010, 4, 9)]]],
      dtype=object)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2006-08-30 2007-08-30 2008-08-29 2009-08-30
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 172.4 172.5
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -41.38 -41.42
```

and

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 4, longitude: 2, latitude: 2)>
array([[[datetime.date(2007, 5, 10), datetime.date(2007, 8, 7)],
        [datetime.date(2007, 9, 23), datetime.date(2007, 7, 8)]],

       [[datetime.date(2008, 5, 17), datetime.date(2008, 8, 19)],
        [datetime.date(2007, 9, 29), datetime.date(2008, 7, 24)]],

       [[datetime.date(2009, 5, 19), datetime.date(2009, 8, 22)],
        [datetime.date(2009, 9, 27), datetime.date(2009, 7, 21)]],

       [[datetime.date(2010, 5, 2), datetime.date(2010, 7, 1)],
        [datetime.date(2010, 8, 24), datetime.date(2010, 6, 13)]]],
      dtype=object)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2006-09-30 2007-09-30 2008-09-29 2009-09-30
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 172.4 172.5
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -41.38 -41.42
    fstar      <U4 '2820'
```

That is, the spatial data is itself time. For each location, there is therefore a period: a start and an end (the end is always after the start). I am struggling to come up with a method of using these as a time slice to index into the rainfall record, and produce a value that is **a sum of the rainfall over the indicated period, for each cell, for each year**.

I know that it is possible to use a DataArray of time values to select into the rainfall data, like so:

```py
rain_at_start = rain_dataset.sel(time=start_data_array)
rain_at_end = rain_dataset.sel(time=end_data_array)
```

Following this principle, it seems at least a little bit plausible to attempt:

```
rain_in_period = rain_ds.sel(time=slice(start_data_array, end_data_array)).rain.sum().compute()
```

However I'm not surprised this doesn't work as it would result in data with strange dimensionality. The error is as follows:

```
ValueError: cannot use non-scalar arrays in a slice for xarray indexing: <xarray.DataArray (longitude: 243, latitude: 260)>
```

This led me to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69667873/is-it-possible-to-selecting-dataset-by-time-range-when-range-is-different-for-ev), the accepted answer for which is underwhelming because it seems to require the enumeration of the time index (...and it doesn't work anyway). The other answer (an approach with a `stack` of latitude and longitude) requires a (presumably, very slow) loop of the constructed lat/lon MultiIndex, and still results in the same ValueError as above on the very first iteration.

Rather I can imagine that there's a way to do this with `apply_ufunc` and core dimensions, but I don't understand the relevant transformations that need to be applied to make this idea work (if it is even possible with vectorized functions).

I have attempted various other contortions of this data, including using `stack` with longitude and latitude, but frankly they are very blind attempts and none have got me anywhere useful so I have omitted them.